# How to store ONNX Machine learning Model as a Hexadecimal string for Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-synapse, onnx

I've already created a Model.onnx file, how can I convert in to .hex format to make prediction by SQL Script in Azure Synapse?
I read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-predict) but still can't understand how to do it. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Train a model in synapse studio which includes machine learning libraries and apache spark. Here the major requirement is to make ONNX supportive create, register and use model.

We can deploy the ONNX model to a table in SQL database pool using Synapse studio which leads to implement complete ONNX deployment using Synapse studio without coming out of that environment and using the notebook within the environment. Please Checkout the [repository](https://github.com/solliancenet/azure-synapse-analytics-workshop-400/blob/master/day-03/lab06-machine-learning.md#exercise-1---synapse-machine-learning-in-action) .

For more information refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HVtcnTdg1A&t=3864s).